# "Assert and return" macro in Google Test?

Tags: c++, testing, assert, googletest

Is there any `ASSERT_AND_RETURN` macro in Google Test that tests something, and if it is false, raises an assertion and returns a value?

Comment: ASSERT_xxx will fail the test and stop it in its tracks. Did you mean EXPECT_AND_RETURN?

Comment: Why would I call it expect if expect in gtest means to continue forward?
I mean something like this:
bool Foo() {
... 
ASSERT_AND_RETURN(x != 0, false);
int y = 1 / x;
...
}

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Actually every `ASSERT_XXX` returns from function - but it does not return value - it is assumed that the function (in most cases functions created by `TESTxx` macros) are void function.

This is sometimes issue when you use `ASSERT_XXX` within function called from another function.  To check if function failed on assert - you need to use [`ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE`](https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#asserting-on-subroutines).

See example

```
void assertNotNull(int *p)
{
    ASSERT_THAT(p, NotNull(p));
}
void assertSizeIs(int actual, int expected)
{
    ASSERT_EQ(actual, expected);
}
TEST(A, B)
{
   std::pair<int*,int> p = createArray(7);

   ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE(assertNotNull(p.first));
   ASSERT_NO_FATAL_FAILURE(assertSizeIs(p.second, 7));
   
   for( int i = 0; i < 7; ++i) 
      ASSERT_EQ(0, p.first[i]);
}
```

Comment: The link to the docs is stale. It should be updated to https://google.github.io/googletest/advanced.html#asserting-on-subroutines . Unfortunately, the suggested edit queue is full and I do not have enough reputation to review things in the queue :(